# EBS Snapshots, who manages backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup, snapshot, amazon-ebs

I'm starting with AWS and I've been taking my first steps on EC2 and EBS. I've learnt about EBS snapshots but I still don't understand if the backups, once you've created a snapshot, are managed automatically by AWS  or I need to do them on my own.

Comment: EBS snapshots are not taken automatically, You have to take it manually whenever you required it.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Ok, now I get it. Many thanks!

Comment: You can automate it using https://totalcloud.io. Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshots are managed by AWS

snapshot of an EBS volume, can be used as a baseline for new volumes or for data backup. If you make periodic snapshots of a volume, the snapshots are incremental—only the blocks on the device that have changed after your last snapshot are saved in the new snapshot. Even though snapshots are saved incrementally,

the built in durability of EBS is comparable to a RAID in the physical sense. The data itself is mirrored (think more like a RAID stripe though) in the availability zone where the volume exists. Amazon states that the failure rate is somewhere around 0.1-0.5% annually. This is more reliable than most physical RAID setups

Comment: Thanks a lot! That means that I have to manually make periodic snapshots of a volume if I want it to be incremental, right? I thought AWS would do this for me automatically after I manually created the snapshot of an EBS for the first time.

Comment: @NeoSennin correct.  Any snapshots *you make* are stored in an incremental (deduplicated) fashion... but you have to make each one manually or via the API.  You can still restore any one of them after deleting any previous snapshots, because the system never purges data needed to restore any snapshot, even if it was originally captured by a previous snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

AWS just introduced a new feature called Lifecycle Manager (in the EC2 Dashboard, at the bottom left) that allows you to create automated backups for your volumes. Once you configure a policy, AWS will handle the backup process for your volumes.

This is only a couple of weeks old so just wanted to mention here.